# update a column so that it follows a sequence of numbers

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to `update` a column so that it follows a sequence of numbers but this is only for a small portion of rows in the column.

I am using IB expert. The table is called `CUSTOMERS` and the column is called `CUSTOMERCODE`.

The `CUSTOMERCODES` are currently in `alphanumeric` so I need to change them to `numeric` only.

The **`customercodes`** are from **`0000000000BM001 to 000000000BM099.`**

Comment: How **`many records`** are there in your table, and provide the **primary key.**

Comment: There are 677 records and the primary key is the customercode

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `Update Query`

```
update CUSTOMERS
set CUSTOMERCODE=SUBSTRING(CUSTOMERCODE,len(CUSTOMERCODE)-2,2) 
where CUSTOMERCODE>= '0000000000BM001'
and CUSTOMERCODE<= '000000000BM099'
```

Comment: Give me a Sec, i will fixed it.

Comment: update CUSTOMERS
set CUSTOMERCODE=SUBSTRING(CUSTOMERCODE,len(CUSTOMERCODE)-2,2) 
where CUSTOMERCODE>= '0000000000BM001'
and CUSTOMERCODE<= '000000000BM099'        (I am getting an error at the customercoDE (between D and E, thats where the cursor is) after I execute

Comment: What do you mean by ***getting an error at the customercoDE (between D and E, thats where the cursor is)*** can you please explain ?